# Facebook PHP-SDK or GET request on Graph API?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I am new to this field, and I would like to build a small external PHP application based on Facebook API and data from users.
I found that I can use the **PHP-SDK**
 `$results = $facebook->api('/fql', array('q'=>'FQL_QUERY'));` 
or a **GET request** to
    http://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=FQL_QUERY_HERE

What is the best method to use? Are there any difference in speed?
How can I make a GET request? using *get file contents*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Facebook is committed to the Graph API being the future of their platform and to best future proof your app you will probably want to follow suit.

I would recommend using the CURL functions in PHP to make your request as they are generally considered to be the fastest and most versatile.

```
$c = curl_init("http://graph.facebook.com/1");

// necessary so CURL doesn't dump the results on your page
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$result = curl_exec($c);
curl_close ($c);

$facebookUser = json_decode($result);
print_r($facebookUser);
```

Answer (score 1):

Facebook's php sdk uses curl to get the content whle you make the GET request by using file_get_content.

Tests/Benchmarks show that curl is faster most of the times. So, I'd suggest you to use PHP-SDK (I use it instead of making get requests).

Answer (score 0):

Use the official facebook php api.  This uses the graph API underneath.  It provides all the wrapper functionality needed to use facebook's rich Graph API.

The official API is at: https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk